# Effects of inert gas on heterogenous equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium, phase

What is the effect of the presence of an inert gas on a reversible reaction that was in more than one phase, such as a decomposition reaction?  If a solid or liquid or compound in aqueous solution decomposed in a reversible reaction, and one or more of the products was a gas, would the equilibrium shift if an inert gas was added and volume and temperature were kept constant (so total pressure would increase)?

Comment: Henry's Law would say that the inert gas does not affect the solubility of the gas that's involved in the reaction.

Comment: An inert gas (i.e.; unreactive gas) will not affect a stable equilibrium. Neither will adding a catalyst.

Comment: @Zhe I am not sure how applicable Henry's law is to this situation. In equilibrium, Le Chatelier's principle would suggest that the reaction would shift towards the side that produces less gases.

Comment: No, Le Châtelier's Principle only applies to the components involved in the equilibrium. If you add a gas that is not involved in the equilibrium, there is no shift. The reaction quotient $Q$ would have contributions from the partial pressure of the gas.

Comment: @Zhe The temperature and volume is kept constant. As a result, the reaction will shift its equilibrium to the side that reduces pressure. A similar thing happens for heat.

Comment: @QuantumCAPUCCINO I don't think that's correct. Consider the simple case of a closed container with just water and water vapor. If you inject helium into the closed container. The vapor pressure, which is just a function of temperature, is constant. You do not shift the equilibrium.